# Trying to Upload Multiple Images to Facebook and Twitter with Buffer REST API

Tags: facebook, rest, api, twitter, social-media

I'm using the Buffer REST API to schedule several posts to Facebook and Twitter.

https://buffer.com/developers/api

It's going well, except for the fact that I can't figure out how to attach several images at once for a post, so that the post will showcase all of the images in an album-like format you often see on Facebook.

I've tried a couple of things, like listing the `media[photo]` attribute twice with different images:

```
 {
   'access_token': process.env.BUFFER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
   'text': 'Some text to post',
   'media[photo]': 'http://www.someimage.com/image.jpg',
   'media[photo]': 'http://www.someotherimage.com/image.jpg',
   'profile_ids[]': [12349, 123456]
 }
```

And I've also tried containing those images inside their own array, like this:

```
 {
   ...other items,
   'media[photo]': ['http://www.someimage.com/image.jpg', 'http://www.someotherimage.com/image.jpg'],
 }
```

Nevertheless, only ONE of those images is actually attached to the schedule post when I view it in the Buffer UI.

Has anyone had any success doing this, or should I look to a different tool to accomplish it? Maybe Hootsuite?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what makes you think that it is possible to upload multiple photos at once to facebook? there are many stackoverflow threads telling you that it´s not possible, and there is no mention about it in the official docs either. there is a only a workaround for unpublished posts.

Comment: The Facebook UI allows it. This is what makes me think it's possible. And Stack Overflow threads you mention are either 1) extremely old, or 2) not contextually specific to a REST API. My question stands.

Comment: the threads on stackoverflow are still correct and up to date. if you found them anyway, you should add them to your question so we know what you researched already.